# Feature: From the list of questions be able to add a tag to either ignored or interested

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I would like to be able to set a tag to interesting or ignored from the list of questions. I was thinking maybe when you hover over a tag it could fade in a box with two buttons "Ignore" and "Interesting". On click it adds it to the lists at the top and fades or highlights that question.

Maybe use hover intent to not make it so annoying and don't pop up directly over the tag but below or above as to not block the users view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already do this from any `/questions/tagged` page

like so:

[image]

Comment: Amusingly, I clearly remember people saying "who would ever use this?" when it was added. There's a good chance it was me

Comment: Okay I see, I feel a bit silly now but any idea why is this only available from the "featured" page and not the landing page?